# Fragments and getFragmentManager and version compatibility

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am fairly new to coding and have looked everywhere but may not be looking correctly. I am having a problem with the placeholders. Not sure to have the support or not for the fragment manager being it is v7 support

```
Error:(21, 32) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ListFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ListFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Here is my code

```
 package chris.smellslikebacon;




 import android.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements            ListFragment.OnRecipeSelectedInterface {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListFragment savedFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.placeholders);
    if(savedFragment == null) {
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeholders, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
@Override
public void onListRecipeSelected(int index) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Recipes.names[index],      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use getSupportFragmentManager instead for support:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Hope this helps.